# How to handle in memory cache with Azure App service auto scale

Tags: azure, caching, autoscaling, azure-webapps

I have a Web app hosted in azure App service. The application has an in-memory cache. Planning to enable the auto-scale in app service when the server traffic is high.
What will happen to the in-memory cache?
What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you will have *n* in-memory cache instances. That might be ok, but you might want to look at a distributed cache like [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cache/) or another ready made distributed implementation of IMemoryCache as found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-6.0#establish-distributed-caching-services) (assuming you use .Net):

- Distributed SQL Server cache
- Distributed Redis cache
- Distributed NCache cache

If you keep using the in-memory cache, each new web app instance will start with an empty cache and it will fill based on the requests to that particular instance.